# help with complex second order differential equation and NDSolve

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration, nonlinear, boundary-condition-at-infinity

I have a complicated 2nd ODE with boundary values. It is actually a vector so there are three ODEs and they are coupled. I would like to solve for `sx[x]`, `sy[x]`, `sz[x]` with the boundaries `sx[0] = 1` and `sy[0] = 0`, and `sz[0] = 0`. Also also`sx[L] = sy[L] = sz[L] = 0` where `L` should be infinity but I'm not sure if that's allowed. So I just take it to be a large number. Note that the `s[x]`'s exist in the denominator of one of the terms and are non-linear.

I have tried this with `NDSolve` as you can see below. 
For some values of the parameters I can achieve results in reasonable amount of time. But if I make, for instance, `Bz` too large (like 10), mathematica slows down considerably and I may get errors.

I would like to know if I can hope to use `NDSolve` to find solutions for a broad range of input parameters. And if not, I suspect that a finite different method must be used. I have seen a canned finite difference method for ODEs but it was not general enough to account for the complex form and nonlinearity that I have here. If someone could help me get started on putting this into a finite difference framework, or pointing me to good resources, that would also be appreciated.

```
B = {0, 0, Bz};

params = {Ex -> 1., m -> 0.5, d -> 4., 
Bz -> 1., g -> 1., tau -> 1., be -> 0.1, BL -> 0.01, 
bN -> -1, L -> 20., s0 -> 1.};

sol = Flatten[
 NDSolve[{d {sx''[x], sy''[x], sz''[x]} + m Ex {sx'[x], 
        sy'[x], sz'[x]} + g  Cross[
        B + bN  #.(B + be #)/((B + be #).(B + be #) + 
           BL^2) (B + be #), #] - #/tau == {0., 0., 0.},
    sx[L] == 0., sy[L] == 0., sz[L] == 0., sx[0.] == s0, 
    sy[0.] == 0., sz[0.] == 0.} /. params, {sx[x], sy[x], 
   sz[x]}, {x, 0, 20.}] ] &[{sx[x], sy[x], sz[x]}];

Sx = sx[x] /. sol;
Sy = sy[x] /. sol;
Sz = sz[x] /. sol;
```

Comment: `Cross[B + bN #.(B + be #)/((B + be #).(B + be #) + BL^2) (B + be #), #] &[{sx[x], sy[x], sz[x]}]` has a `LeafCount` of 3843.  After `Simplify` it drops to 191, suggesting that the ODEs should be simplified before being inserted into `NDSolve`.  Also, for the parameters given `sz[x]` is zero.  Deleting it from the set of ODEs could improve speed somewhat.

Comment: The result of these changes is to reduce runtime from 146 sec to 18 sec.

Comment: sz[x] will not be zero in general. But thanks for the LeafCount info - was not aware of that function.

Comment: @bbgodfrey When I run this I am getting an error in apparently in `FindRoot` that it is maxed out at 100 iterations. I am not using `FindRoot` but I presume that `NDSolve` is. How can I increase the iterations in this case?

Comment: Search [here](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NDSolveBVP.html#659822336) for the second instance of `FindRoot`, just before the Chasing Method section.

Comment: According to my limited experience, finite difference method (FDM) is more likely to fail when dealing with boundary value problem (BVP) of nonlinear ODE. (It needs a good enough initial guess in the whole domain! ) If your problem can't be handled by `NDSolve`,  I'm afraid FDM won't help, either. (FDM will always give you an answer of course, but it's probably wrong. )

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Numerical Solution**

The following actions greatly improve speed and accuracy for the particular ODE system in the question.  First, the function involving

```
Cross[B + bN  #.(B + be #)/((B + be #).(B + be #) + BL^2) (B + be #), #] &
    [{sx[x], sy[x], sz[x]}]
```

should be performed outside `NDSolve` and `Simplify` applied to the result to reduce running time by an order of magnitude or so.  Moreover, with `B` perpendicular to `Ex`, as is the case here, the component of `s` parallel to `B`, here `sz`, is zero and can be omitted from the problem.  Next, use the "Shooting" `Method` with increased "MaxIterations".  Finally, as `Bz` is increased, `L` can be decreased.  With these changes, the problem with `Bz == 10` becomes

```
sol = Flatten@NDSolve[{d {sx''[x], sy''[x]} + m Ex {sx'[x], sy'[x]} + 
    g  {-((Bz sy[x] (BL^2 + Bz^2 + be (be + bN) sx[x]^2 + 
          be (be + bN) sy[x]^2))/(BL^2 + Bz^2 + be^2 sx[x]^2 + be^2 sy[x]^2)), 
          (Bz sx[x] (BL^2 + Bz^2 + be (be + bN) sx[x]^2 + 
          be (be + bN) sy[x]^2))/(BL^2 + Bz^2 + be^2 sx[x]^2 + be^2 sy[x]^2)} - 
        {sx[x], sy[x]}/tau == {0, 0}, 
        sx[L] == 0, sy[L] == 0, sx[0] == s0, sy[0] == 0} /. params, 
    {sx[x], sy[x]}, {x, 0, 10}, 
    Method -> {"Shooting", "StartingInitialConditions" -> {sx[0] == s0 /. params, 
    sy[0] == 0, sx'[0] == -1, sy'[0] == 1}, "MaxIterations" -> 500}];
```

and produces a result in seconds.

```
Plot[{sx[x], sy[x]} /. sol, {x, 0, 10}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

**Approximate Symbolic Solution**

It is worth noting that the ODE system can be solved approximately with `DSolve` for large `Bz` or for large `x`.

```
asol = Flatten@DSolve[{d {sx''[x], sy''[x]} + m Ex {sx'[x], sy'[x]} + 
  g {-Bz sy[x] , Bz sx[x]} - {sx[x], sy[x]}/tau == {0, 0}}, {sx[x], sy[x]}, x] // Simplify;
```

Although the result is far too lengthy to display here, its exponential factors can be isolated without difficulty.

```
aexp = Simplify[Union@Cases[asol // Expand, Exp[_], Infinity]]
(* {E^(-((Ex m x + (Sqrt[4 d + 4 I Bz d g tau + Ex^2 m^2 tau] x)/Sqrt[tau])/(2 d))), 
    E^(-((Ex m x + (Sqrt[4 d - 4 I Bz d g tau + Ex^2 m^2 tau] x)/Sqrt[tau])/(2 d))), 
    E^(-((Ex m x - (Sqrt[4 d + 4 I Bz d g tau + Ex^2 m^2 tau] x)/Sqrt[tau])/(2 d))), 
    E^(-((Ex m x - (Sqrt[4 d - 4 I Bz d g tau + Ex^2 m^2 tau] x)/Sqrt[tau])/(2 d)))} *)
```

Only the exponentially decaying terms satisfy the boundary conditions at large `L`.  The growing solutions can be eliminated as follows.

```
asolsx = Collect[((sx[x] /. asol) // Expand) /. 
    Exp[z_] :> Exp[Simplify[z]], {Exp[_], C[_]}, Simplify];
asolsy = Collect[((sy[x] /. asol) // Expand) /. 
    Exp[z_] :> Exp[Simplify[z]], {Exp[_], C[_]}, Simplify];
c24 = Collect[Flatten@Solve[{Coefficient[asolsx, aexp[[3]]] == 0, 
    Coefficient[asolsx, aexp[[4]]] == 0}, {C[2], C[4]}], C[_], Simplify];
asolsx1 = Collect[asolsx /. c24, {Exp[_], C[_]}, Simplify]
asolsy1 = Collect[asolsy /. c24, {Exp[_], C[_]}, Simplify]
(* aexp[[1]] (C[1]/2 - 1/2 I C[3]) + aexp[[2]] (C[1]/2 + 1/2 I C[3]) *)
(* aexp[[2]] (-(1/2) I C[1] + C[3]/2) + aexp[[1]] (1/2 I C[1] + C[3]/2) *)
```

where `aexp[[1]]` and `aexp[[2]]` have been written in place of the corresponding exponentials solely for notational simplicity.  The remaining constants are evaluated from

```
{asolsx1 == 1, asolsy1 == 0} /. x -> 0 /. Equal -> Rule
(* {C[1] -> 1, C[3] -> 0} *)
```

and

```
Plot[{asolsx1, asolsy1} /. % /. params, {x, 0, 10}, PlotRange -> All]
```

gives a plot indistinguishable to the eye from the plot above.  Thus, we have a good symbolic solution for `BL^2 + Bz^2` large compared `be^2` and `Abs[be (be + bN)]`.

When this is not the case, these solutions instead can be used to obtain superior boundary conditions at large `L`, allowing `L` to be reduced in magnitude.  Doing so is useful, because numerical solutions with `NDSolve` inevitably pick up some of the exponentially growing solutions, causing loss of precision in fitting the boundary conditions at `L`.  To generate these boundary conditions, first construct

```
Simplify[asolsx1 + I asolsy1]
(* aexp[[2]] (C[1] + I C[3]) *)
```

and take its logarithmic derivative.

```
bc = D[Log[sx[x] + I sy[x]], x] == D[Log[%], x]
(* (Derivative[1][sx][x] + I Derivative[1][sy][x])/(sx[x] + I sy[x]) == 
   -((Ex m + Sqrt[4 d - 4 I Bz d g tau + Ex^2 m^2 tau]/Sqrt[tau])/(2 d)) *)
```

The Real and Imaginary parts of `bc` are the desired boundary conditions.  For instance, with `Bz == 10`, as above,

```
sx[x] + I sy[x] == ComplexExpand[(Derivative[1][sx][x] + I Derivative[1][sy][x])/
    N[Last@bc /. params]]
(* sx[x] + I sy[x] == -0.674697 Derivative[1][sx][x] + I (-0.514645 Derivative[1][sx][x] - 
   0.674697 Derivative[1][sy][x]) + 0.514645 Derivative[1][sy][x] *)
{bc1, bc2} = Thread[{sx[x], sy[x]} == Refine[ReIm[%[[2]]], 
    Derivative[1][sx][x] | Derivative[1][sy][x]) ∈ Reals]] /. x -> L
(* {sx[L] == -0.674697 Derivative[1][sx][L] + 0.514645 Derivative[1][sy][L], 
    sy[L] == -0.514645 Derivative[1][sx][L] - 0.674697 Derivative[1][sy][L]} *)
```